# How do you run a Repast Browser Model on your own server?

Tags: repast-simphony

I understand [from here](https://repast.github.io/docs/RepastNG/browser.html) that you can use a browser to display a repast model by running it on local server. I would like to run a repast browser model on a Linux VPS server and allow public access via an URL. Is this possible at this moment? What are the next steps?

I am a beginner with Linux servers but I assume it would take something like this:

1. Install Java on the server
2. Transfer the Repast model to the server
3. Connect the URL to run a (to that user unique) model on the server
4. Connect the URL to display the model

Comment: You could run each Repast Browser Model instance in their own tmux/screen session (assuming Repast support such feature) and different ports, then have nginx/apache forward http request for certain paths into their associated ports. If you want the user to be able to customize which model they load at runtime, then you'd have to build a webapp that pass user input into Repast launch parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the information Martheen.
It sounds like this is not common practice yet. Do you know of anyone who did this? Or a website with an example?

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/javaservers/

Comment: Thanks for the link. So nginx.com is a cloud service where I can host the application. I am planning to run it on a VPS Ubuntu Linux Server I'll buy. However, the procedure you gave might relate to that.

Comment: Nginx is an *app*, you can install it on any Linux server.